# pyomo constraints section missing

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming, pyomo

I'm new at using pyomo and getting following error:
/var/folders/dk/932rtpm52sg0jdzzkz81mhn00000gn/T/tmp7Psz4a.pyomo.lp:5: constraints section missing

My constraint is:

```
matrix_bis = np.ones((size_node, size_node))
c11_param = matrix_bis.copy()
c11_param = np.tril(c11_param)
param11 = np.dot(c11_param, m.Y)

# Constraints
def c11_rule(m,j):
    for e in node_set:
        return (data.ix[e, 'cp_min'], c11_param[e,j]*m.Y[e], data.ix[e, 'cp_max']/interval)
    else:
        return pe.Constraint.Skip
m.c11 = pe.Constraint(node_set, rule = c11_rule)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your error but the first issue I see is that you don't need the for loop inside of the constraint rule. By declaring the Constraint as indexed over node_set the rule will automatically be called once for every value in node_set. It looks like you are distinguishing between the index 'e' and the index 'j' in c11_param so I'm guessing that you want to index the constraint over the cross product of node_set. You also don't need Constraint.Skip. Maybe something like this:

```
def c11_rule(m, j, e):
    return (data.ix[e,'cp_min'], c11_param[e,j]*m.Y[e], data.ix[e, 'cp_max']/interval)
m.c11 = Constraint(node_set, node_set, rule=c11_rule)
```